# OpenglES 2.0 GL_POINTS disappear

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I am using gl_points as sprites, when points reach screen boundary they disappear, problem is that my points are larger than 1 pixel, so they disappear when half of point beaks trough screen bound, i am assuming that there is some kind of culling turned on to remove points that are offscreen, question is how to turn it off.

Comment: increasing viewport helps in this case :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Increasing viewport size helps, or you can render it to texture and zoom :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    GLES20Renderer.programLight = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    int vertexShaderLight       = GLES20Renderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, GLES20Renderer.vertexShaderCodeLight);
    int fragmentShaderLight     = GLES20Renderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, GLES20Renderer.fragmentShaderCodeLight);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(GLES20Renderer.programLight, vertexShaderLight);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(GLES20Renderer.programLight, fragmentShaderLight);
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(GLES20Renderer.programLight);
    uPLocationLight             = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(GLES20Renderer.programLight, "uP");
    uVPositionLocationLight     = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(GLES20Renderer.programLight, "uVPosition");

    GLES20.glUseProgram(GLES20Renderer.programLight);
    GLES20.glUniform4f(uVPositionLocationLight, LightPosInEyeSpace[0], LightPosInEyeSpace[1], LightPosInEyeSpace[2], LightPosInEyeSpace[3]);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uPLocationLight, 1, false, ProjectionMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, 1);


private static final String vertexShaderCodeLight = 
        "uniform vec4 uVPosition;                   \n"
    +   "uniform mat4 uP;                           \n"
    +   "void main(){                               \n"
    +   " gl_PointSize = 15.0;                      \n"
    +   " gl_Position = uP * uVPosition;            \n"
    +   "}                                          \n";
private static final String fragmentShaderCodeLight = 
        "#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH          \n"
    +   "precision highp float;                     \n"
    +   "#else                                      \n"
    +   "precision mediump float;                   \n"
    +   "#endif                                     \n"
    +   "void main(){                               \n"
    +   " gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);     \n"
    +   "}                                          \n";
```

Answer (score 0):

GL_POINTS are clipped at the center.  This is just a limitation of GL_POINTS.  If you can't live with this just use regular quads (assuming performance can deal with it)

Comment: i know, thats why i have increased viewport size, so its bigger by two point sizes in x and y and points are renderred fine now